# How do you get the 'Rules Breaker' achievement?

Tags: goscurry

I'm having trouble with one of the the miscellaneous achievements in Goscurry.

> RULES BREAKER | Avoid an obstacle without jumping/evading

How do you do that?

[image: RULES BREAKER | Avoid an obstacle without jumping/evading]

Answer (score -1):

HINT: it has to do with turning (2X) instead than jumping/evading ;)